# Begin and Finish or Pre and Post in async call pair?

Tags: naming

In an async call pair you would rather have a BeginDoSomething & FinishDoSomething or PreDoingSomething & PostDoingSomething pair?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the method **causes** the async functionality **to begin**, then I would call it `Begin...`.

If the method **causes** the async functionality **to end**, then I would call it `End...`

If the method should be **run before** the async functionality starts, then I might call it `Pre...`

If the method should be **run after** the async functionality ends, then I might call it `Post...`

The begin and end options seem to indicate that they cause things to happen with respect to the async function, like turning the key in the ignition, or turning it off again.

The pre and post options seem to indicate that they are detached from the actual async function they surround, like closing the car door before you put your foot on the accelerator, or putting on the handbrake before exiting the car.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer **pre** and **post** but those are naming conventions that are personal preference. There is not right or wrong.